# How to set default date value as current date in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm making an Action for the Google Assistant, and got stuck with this issue. I want to set default current date with my intent and send it to my webhook.. I'm using nodejs as my webhook, please tell me any possible solution. Thank you

Comment: It is a little difficult to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you show a screen shot of the Intent you're currently working with, and possibly the webhook code as well, and provide an illustration of what you think the conversation should sound like?

Comment: I also have a date parameter for one of my intents with a default value set to "Today" but DialogFlow does not seem to honor it (it will still ask for the date if the user did not specify it).

Comment: @carloshwa I finally find the solution, you shouldn't define date parameter if you want to get default date or current date from the intent because whenever your request generate from dialogflow for any intent the current date property also attached in your request's json object...